# How to read data from .db file stored on my local machine in asp .net core web api?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have database file stored in my D drive want to read data from that file by using query .

I am already using entity framework and accessing one database from that sql server db , but I want to access one other data from that .db file in same function and as I am new to asp .net core not aware of how to access that

Comment: What type of database you use? What framework for working with data? Entity Framework? So, in common you should specify connection string. Data reader is not depends on type of data. In connection string you can specifi   path to file. For example here is an connection string for MDF database: "Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;"AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\SampleDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True"

Comment: I am already using entity framework and accessing one database from that   sql server db , but I want to access one other data from that .db file in same function and as I am new to asp .net core not aware of how to access that .

Comment: Then you should create one new namespace and create there all that need to work with this database (Entity objects, Contexts, and so one). And specifi in configuration another connection strings for new DB context.